# How to reuse Jasmine tests

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, jasmine, protractor

I have the following test in Jasmine, that I need to execute for 2 different URLs, these 2 url are different versions of the same product:

```
describe('TEST ',function(){
    var basePage = new BasePage();
    var page1 = new Page1();

    describe('TEST',function(){

        beforeEach(function(){
            browser.get('URL-1.html');
        });

        it('REUSE THIS TEST' , function (){
            browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(viewerWidgetPage.videoPlayer));
            page1.videoControls.click();
            expect(basePage.hasClass(page1.videoPlayer, 'vjs-playing')).toBeTruthy();
            page1.audioControl.click();

            //Verify that the video property is muted.
            browser.executeAsyncScript_(function(callback){
                callback(window.player.muted());
            }).then(function(isMuted){
                expect(isMuted).toBeFalsy();
            });

            page1.audioControl.click();

            //Verify that the video property is muted.
            browser.executeAsyncScript_(function(callback){
                callback(window.player.muted());
            }).then(function(isMuted){
                expect(isMuted).toBeTruthy();
            });


        });

    });
```

Is there any way to use in another test, the 'it' "REUSE THIS TEST" in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to *loop over the URLs under test*:

```
describe('TEST ',function(){
    var basePage = new BasePage();
    var page1 = new Page1();
    var urls = ['URL-1.html', 'URL-2.html'];

    urls.map(function (url) {
        describe('TEST ' + url,function(){

            beforeEach(function(){
                browser.get(url);
            });

            it('REUSE THIS TEST' , function (){
                browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(viewerWidgetPage.videoPlayer));
                page1.videoControls.click();
                expect(basePage.hasClass(page1.videoPlayer, 'vjs-playing')).toBeTruthy();
                page1.audioControl.click();

                //Verify that the video property is muted.
                browser.executeAsyncScript_(function(callback){
                    callback(window.player.muted());
                }).then(function(isMuted){
                    expect(isMuted).toBeFalsy();
                });

                page1.audioControl.click();

                //Verify that the video property is muted.
                browser.executeAsyncScript_(function(callback){
                    callback(window.player.muted());
                }).then(function(isMuted){
                    expect(isMuted).toBeTruthy();
                });


            });
        });
    });
});
```

---

Another approach, that would probably scale better, would be to use `multiCapabilities` and to add the desired spec(s) to each of the capabilities parameterizing the url under test.

The idea is to define the parameter on every capability:

```
multiCapabilities: [
    {
        browserName: "chrome",
        url: "URL-1.html"
    },
    {
        browserName: "chrome",
        url: "URL-2.html"
    }
],
```

Then, in your test use [`getProcessedConfig()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.getProcessedConfig) to access the current capability and the `url`:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function (config) {
        var url = config.capabilities.url;
        browser.get(url);
    });
});
```

Tested - works for me.